# Way to make ISO date-time format universal throughout Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, locale

Everything in ubuntu has different date-time formats. It is crazy. Is there a way to set the standard ISO date-time format (e.g., 2014-05-03T12:31) universally throughout ubuntu so that the ISO format overrides EVERYTHING?

I currently have my locale set to an ISO standard (i.e., en_DK) but it is next to useless because few things obeys it. Terminal/Bash doesn't obey it. Nautilus doesn't obey it. the watch-command doesn't obey it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no. I.e. not without changing all programs which don't pay regard to the selected locale for date and time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you configured it according to your distro's normal way and it works for some software, but not all. To get the remaining software to start displaying time according to system locale you should:

#### For open-source software:

- open issues on their bug trackers to let them know you want this.

If you want things to go faster:

- do it yourself and submit pull requests.
- offer them enough money to work on this feature for you.

#### For closed-source software:

- ask them via some contact option (bug tracker, suggestions forum, Twitter, email).